# Using \tag in unnumbered versions

Tags: cross-referencing, numbering, amsmath

According to the [`amsmath` documentation](ftp://ftp.ams.org/pub/tex/doc/amsmath/amsldoc.pdf) (section 3.1, page 7)

> `\tag` and `\tag*` can also be used within the unnumbered versions of all
>   the amsmath alignment structures

It provides no examples (surprise!). But my code

```
\documentclass[12pt,fleqn,reqno]{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts,graphics,epsfig,cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx,amssymb,amsthm}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    \mathbf{u}(t) &= 2\sum_{n=1}^N A_n \cos(k_n t) \mathbf{v}_n \\
        &= 2\left(A_2 \cos(k_2 t)\mathbf{v}_2 + A_N \cos(k_N t)\mathbf{v}_N\right) \\
        &= 2\left(A_2 \cos(k_2 t)\mathbf{v}_2 + A_2^* \cos(k_2 t)\mathbf{v}_2^*\right) \\
        &= 2 \cos(k_2 t) \left(A_2 \mathbf{v}_2 + A_2^* \mathbf{v}_2^*\right) \\
        &= 2 \cos(k_2 t) \big(A_2 \mathbf{v}_2 + (A_2 \mathbf{v}_2)^*\big) \\
        &= 2 \cos(k_2 t) 2 \Re(A_2 \mathbf{v}_2) \\
        &= 4 \cos(k_2 t) \Re(A_2 \mathbf{v}_2) \\
... \\
    \mathbf{u}(t) &= \cos(k_2 t) \mathbf{u}(0) \tag{eq:exactSolution}
.\end{align*}
The velocities at time $t$ is the derivative of \eqref{eq:exactSolution}
\begin{equation*}
    \mathbf{\dot{u}}(t) = -k_2 \sin(k_2 t) \mathbf{\dot{u}}(0).
\label{eq:}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

generates the warning

> Reference 'eq:exactSolution' on page 1 undefined on input line 16

even though "eq:exactSolution" is defined 2 lines above the warning. *Please tell me how to fix this*.

Comment: there's an example in the "additional documentation" file `testmath` on p.33; [pdf file here](ftp://ftp.ams.org/pub/tex/amslatex/math/testmath.pdf).  the input file and pdf are included in tex live, and the pdf file can be viewed there with `texdoc testmath`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`\tag{<stuff>}` prints `<stuff>` as the actual tag, not the label. So you need to use

```
\begin{align*}
  %...
  \mathbf{u}(t) &= \cos(k_2 t) \mathbf{u}(0) %
    \stepcounter{equation}\tag{\theequation}\label{eq:exactSolution}
  %...
\end{align*}
...\eqref{eq:exactSolution}...
```

In the above example, I've stepped the `equation` counter and used it in the `\tag`, for consistency. However, you could have used anything.

Comment: Worked perfectly first try.